# Get links with one hypen followed by 4 digits in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

My intention is to extract links like `http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/ks/kansas_governor_brownback_vs_holland-1235.html`

The links should end with a hyphen, 4digits and the html extension

This is my source code

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"http://www\.realclearpolitics\.com/epolls/\d{4}/governor/.+?\-\d{4}\.html"

test_str = "value=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/house/wv/west_virginia_3rd_district_maynard_vs_rahall-1385.html\">West Virginia 3rd District</option> </select></p></div></div><div id=\"leftbox-latest\"><span class=\"sidebar-header\">2010 Governor Races</span><div id=\"poll_sidebar\"><p><strong><img src=\"http://assets.realclearpolitics.com/images/arrow_black.gif\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" width=\"7\" height=\"10\" /><a href=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/2010_elections_governor_map.html\">RealClearPolitics Ratings</a></strong><br /> <strong><img src=\"http://assets.realclearpolitics.com/images/arrow_black.gif\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" width=\"7\" height=\"10\" /><a href=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/2010_elections_governor_map_race_changes.html\">RCP Race-by-Race Changes</a></strong><br /> <strong><img src=\"http://assets.realclearpolitics.com/images/arrow_black.gif\" border=\"0\" alt=\"\" width=\"7\" height=\"10\" /><a href=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/2010_elections_governor_map_final_results.html\">Final Governors Map</a></strong><br /> <select class=\"search_by_race\" name=\"search_by_race\"> <option value=\"#\">Governor Races</option> <option value=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/al/alabama_governor_bentley_vs_sparks-1586.html\">Alabama Governor</option> <option value=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/ak/alaska_governor_parnell_vs_berkowitz-1510.html\">Alaska Governor</option> <option value=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/az/arizona_governor_brewer_vs_goddard-1409.html\">Arizona Governor</option> <option value=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/ar/arkansas_governor_keet_vs_beebe-1568.html\">Arkansas Governor</option> <option value=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/ca/california_governor_whitman_vs_brown-1113.html\">California Governor</option> <option value=\"http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/governor/co/colorado_governor_maes_vs_hickenlooper_vs_tancredo-1677.html\">Colorado Governor</option> <option "

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

the first match is wrong. I do not have any ideas how to exclude the first one and include the rest one. I believe that the regex is doing a greedy search on the hyphen. If this is true, how do I avoid it?

Comment: Can you include your Python code?  And also, just show us a small sample text, not a massive HTML dump; few people here will have the patience to read through it.

Comment: Your code [works for me](http://rextester.com/OUCHQX6072), at least for a shorter input test string.  When I use your code verbatim, I get errors about the input string, not the regex logic, which looks fine to me.

Comment: @virupaksha It looks like in your edit you lost the actual question.

Comment: The first match is wrong. That is the problem. All the others are correct

Comment: i see that I have been downvoted. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How is the regex logic correct? The first match does a non-greedy search on the hyphen

Comment: @bzier I corrected it now

Comment: Maybe I'm missing an edge case which comes out in your longer sample input.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The code above replicates the same error. PLease check again

Comment: See [this demo](http://rextester.com/WPFT25099), are the results expected ones?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, you used `.` that can match any char. You need to restrict that part with `[^"\s]` to match any char but `"` or whitespace.

I suggest you use

```
regex = r'http://www\.realclearpolitics\.com/epolls/\d{4}/governor/[^\s"]+-\d{4}\.html'
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/WPFT25099)

**Details**

- `http://www\.realclearpolitics\.com/epolls/` - a literal `http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/` substring
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `/governor/` - a literal substring
- `[^\s"]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `"`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `\.html` - a `.html` substring.